# How to get list of cms pages based on a particular theme in magento?

Tags: magento, content-management-system, themes

I have created cms pages for two themes of a single store view.
I want to show all the cms pages links in the front end which is specific to the theme.
i.e. only those cms page links should come which is used in a particular theme.
I have used below function to  extract all the cms pages..

```
public function getCMSPages(){

$storeId = $this->helper('core')->getStoreId();
$cms = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1)
                ->addStoreFilter($storeId);
$url = Mage::getBaseUrl();
$html = "";
foreach($cms as $cmspage):
    $page = $cmspage->getData();    
    if($page['identifier'] == "no-route" || $page['identifier'] == "enable-cookies" || $page['identifier'] == "empty"){
         /* do nothing */
     } else {
        if($page['identifier'] == "home"){
            $html .= "<li><a href=\"$url\" title=\"".$page['title']."\">".$page['title']."</a></li>\n";
        } else {
            $html .= "<li><a href=\"$url".$page['identifier']."\" title=\"".$page['title']."\">".$page['title']."</a></li>\n";
        }
    }
endforeach;

return $html;   
}
```

How can I **get cms pages only for a particular theme** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add theme filter `custom_theme` on this field

```
$storeId = $this->helper('core')->getStoreId();
$cms = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1)
                ->addFieldToFilter('custom_theme','default/default')
                ->addStoreFilter($storeId);
```

Comment: In order to use the above code , I have to specify the custom theme for the cms page in the custom design section in the admin panel. Am I right ? @QaisarSatti.

Comment: should I use condition like If(Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme('frontend')=="iphone"){}else{}.. to differentiate the pages ?